# Neo4J - Test nodes on path with unknown depth, with MATCH only

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to test all nodes in the path from node a to node b (with only `MATCH` statement), where the depth is changing (could be any number). In the example below the depth is 2.

```
START a = node(86) 
MATCH p0 = a-[*..2]-b 
WHERE (b.attr = 'true') AND (a.attr = 'true')
RETURN p0
```

My question is how do I test the nodes between a and b for a certain attribute (`attr = 'true'`), using the `MATCH` statement, without knowing the depth required.

I find that using filter method I can filter out all the unwanted nodes.
like:

```
START a = node(86) 
MATCH p0 = a-[*..2]-b 
RETURN filter(x IN nodes(p0) WHERE x.attr = 'true')
```

But that is not what I need, I need to use `MATCH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Cypher refcard](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/), specifically to the [List Predicates section](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#query-predicates). The all() function should do the trick.

Something like:

```
START a=node(86) 
MATCH p0=(a)-[*..2]-(b) 
WHERE ALL(node in nodes(p0) WHERE node.attr = true)
RETURN p0
```

This will only match patterns where all the nodes in the pattern have that attribute as true.

Comment: I hope it fits what you were looking for. If it works for you, please accept the answer. If not, please elaborate and I can work on a fix to better fit your requirements.